# Eigenvectors with many rational entries

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$ is an invertible $3 \times 3$ matrix with integral entries and that $v$ is an eigenvector corresponding to an irrational eigenvalue.  Of course by scaling $v$ we may arrange that it has at least one rational entry.  But is it possible for $v$ to have two rational entries, and only one irrational one?

(Feel free to share any higher-dimensional results, of course!)

Answer (score 7):

$$
\pmatrix{0&2\\ 1&0\\ &&I_{n-2}}\pmatrix{\sqrt{2}\\ 1\\ \mathbf0}=\sqrt{2}\pmatrix{\sqrt{2}\\ 1\\ \mathbf0}.
$$